# can 'ls' output JSON?

Tags: javascript, linux, ls

Is there a parameter to `ls` to force it output data in JSON format?

```
ls -json

[
{"name":"file1", "date":"2014-02-13 15:22:47.004854200 +0700", "size":132017}, 
{"name":"file2", "date":"2014-02-13 15:09:21.004826640 +0700", "size":372323}
]
```

Comment: `man ls` would suggest that there is no such option.  That said, you could spin a script to do it.  Did you have any specific problems while attempting to do it?

Comment: `ls --help`, `man ls` and check

Comment: `info coreutils 'ls invocation'` seem to provide more data than `man`, so I assume that maybe neither is complete

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c

Comment: @exebook Info pages _usually_ provide more information that manpages.